# Semantic UI Popup Arrow position with custom classes

Tags: javascript, css, semantic-ui

I’m using a single div for a popup, and sharing content dynamically. I’ve implemented custom classes to change the border color depending on the content of the triggering element.

The arrow fails to position correctly when the class changes, but in subsequent reveals, without changing classes, the arrow is correct. See screenshots.

1. Left: First appearance with green border, “green arrow” in presumably default position
2. Middle: Second appearance with green border, “green arrow” in correct position pointing to target
3. Right: Next reveal, triggered with red border, “red arrow” in presumably default (incorrect) position again:

[image]

Subsequent reveals on red targets would result in correct arrow positioning. Changing to green or yellow breaks it again.

This doesn’t appear to be a problem when the class doesn’t change.

Any insight you can provide will be most helpful.

These are my class defs:

```
.q-tip .box-success {
    border-color: rgb(96,173,93);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgb(96,173,93,.12), 0 2px 10px 0 rgb(96,173,93,.15) !important;
  }

  .q-tip .box-success:before {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px 0px rgb(96,173,93,1);
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px 0px rgb(96,173,93,1);
  }

  .q-tip .box-caution {
    border-color: rgb(254,231,168);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgb(254,231,168,.12), 0 2px 10px 0 rgb(254,231,168,.15) !important;
  }

  .q-tip .box-caution:before {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px 0px rgb(254,231,168,1);
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px 0px rgb(254,231,168,1);
  }

  .q-tip .box-danger {
    border-color: rgb(166,7,30);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgb(166,7,30,.12), 0 2px 10px 0 rgb(166,7,30,.15) !important;
  }

  .q-tip .box-danger:before {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px 0px rgb(166,7,30,1);
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px 0px rgb(166,7,30,1);
  }
```

**Update**
The same phenomenon occurs when rolling off then back on the target, i.e., first reveal, bad arrow, 2nd reveal, good arrow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved.

The erroneous configuration relied on the [Vue.js](http://vuejs.org) dynamic `:class` attribute binding, changing the class attached to the semantic popup div in reaction to the value of the triggering element:

```
<div id="qt-default" 
     :class="'box-'+status" 
     class="ui wide popup" 
     data-variation="very wide">
```

This just doesn't work--not sure why. After stepping through the semantic code it seems the classname changes appear to be applied consistently before popup animation, but perhaps the positioning algo is affected upstream. I did not proceed to investigate this in detail, assuming the solution lay in the popup component's event handling API instead.

The solution was to change the class in the popup's [`onShow`](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/popup.html#/settings) handler which fires 
when the popup is "requested" (when `show` is called) but before it is visible:

```
  conf.onShow = (e) => {
    const elem = document.getElementById('qt-default')
    elem.classList.remove('box-success','box-caution','box-danger')
    elem.classList.add('box-'+status)
  }
  $(conf.trigger).popup(conf)
  $(conf.trigger).popup('show')
```